# Why Session variable unset

Tags: php, api, 7digital

I am using 7digital API in a PHP project.
Here is my code to calling API:

```
print_r($_SESSION);   

$requestUrl = "http://api.7digital.com/1.2/release/details?oauth_consumer_key=" . SEVEN_DIGITAL_CONSUMER_KEY . "&country=$CountryCode&releaseid=" . $wishlistArray[$i]['release7id'] . "&imageSize=33";
$response = simplexml_load_file($requestUrl);

print_r($_SESSION);
```

It's working fine but here is a problem like:

If i press refresh button one time then session variable is not unsetting means (i can access session data after API calling code) but press again refresh button before loading previous refresh action then session data will be unset automatically.

Means if i press more than one time refresh button continuously then session data automatically destroyed.

What may be reason?

For one time refreshing it's working fine.
If i removed XML loading code then it's working fine to more than one time refreshing or single time refreshing.

Comment: I see nothing that alters the session in any way.

Comment: Where is $_SESSION set ?

Comment: deceze: But session data destroyed after calling API.

Comment: what is the output of $_SESSION?

Comment: can you add session_start(); at the top of the page and check.

Comment: Please try to understand my question.

Comment: I understand your question. But what I am asking is that like what data are you storing in session data. Is that the xml string or any other data ?

Comment: only user info to check user login or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a fairly well-known problem/bug.

See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.simplexml-load-file.php#74192) to get full a full explanation and complete solution.

Comment: Sessions store "XML" just fine. XML is just a string of text. Apparently the *`SimpleXMLElement` class* is buggy when being serialised/unserialised or simply doesn't support it, which is something of a different problem.

Comment: My link to php reference manual does clearly explain the problem...

Comment: Yes, I just want to make sure your general statement "sessions don't like sorting XML" doesn't sound as bad as it does.

Comment: You are right... Just edited my answer... :-)

Answer (score -1):

include session_start(); at the top of your script